# Keeping user logged in with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I have a Java SessionManager class which contains many methods for different login actions with sharedPreferences (such as creating a login session, clearing login session, etc.). I also have a dispatch activity which is launched when the app is run. This dispatch activity calls a method from my SessionManager class to check if a user is currently logged in. If he/she is, and intent takes them to my main activity. Otherwise, the login activity is called where they can then login, etc. However, whenever I run my app, I get an error. My code for my main activity is as follows:

```
public class MainList extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView gradeList;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
public SessionManager session;

static String tab1 = "studentdata";
static String tab2 = "gradebook";
static String tab3 = "weeklysummary";
static String action = "form";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_list);
    Log.e("MESSAGE: ", "In second class");

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);


    Toolbar toolbar;
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tb);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    new infoGetter().execute();

    gradeList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.grade_list);
    LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    lm.setOrientation(lm.VERTICAL);
    gradeList.setLayoutManager(lm);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshGrades();
        }
    });


}


private void refreshGrades(){


    new infoGetter().execute();

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class Wrapper{
    public Elements gradeList;
}

private class infoGetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Wrapper> {

    String studentID = session.getID();
    String username = session.getUser();
    String password = session.getPass();

    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        String loginURL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents/j_security_check";
        String userDataUrl = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=" + tab1 + "&tab2=" + tab2 + "&tab3=" + tab3 + "&studentid=" + studentID + "&action=" + action;

        Connection.Response response = new GradeFetcher().getRequest(userDataUrl);
        Document loggedInDocument = new GradeFetcher().postRequest(loginURL, username, password, studentID, response);
        Elements grades = new GradeFetcher().gradeExtractor(loggedInDocument);

        w.gradeList = grades;
        Log.e("MESSAGE: ","Going to onPostExecute");

        return w;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {

        ArrayList<String>gl = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element e:w.gradeList){
            gl.add(e.text());
        }

        String[]gradeData = gl.toArray(new String[gl.size()]);

        gradeList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.grade_list);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        lm.setOrientation(lm.VERTICAL);
        gradeList.setLayoutManager(lm);
        gradeList.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(gradeData));
    }
}
}
```

and my error is as follows:

```
08-06 21:34:19.970    2010-2010/com.aurum.gradebook E/MESSAGE:﹕ In second class
08-06 21:34:20.018    2010-2010/com.aurum.gradebook E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-06 21:34:20.035    2010-2010/com.aurum.gradebook E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-06 21:34:20.182    2010-2038/com.aurum.gradebook E/GET REQUEST﹕ Making GET request to gradebook page
08-06 21:34:20.183    2010-2038/com.aurum.gradebook E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL              EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.aurum.gradebook, PID: 2010
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data value must not be null
        at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:26)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$KeyVal.value(HttpConnection.java:884)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$KeyVal.create(HttpConnection.java:864)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.data(HttpConnection.java:131)
        at com.aurum.gradebook.GradeFetcher.postRequest(GradeFetcher.java:57)
        at com.aurum.gradebook.MainList$infoGetter.doInBackground(MainList.java:124)
        at com.aurum.gradebook.MainList$infoGetter.doInBackground(MainList.java:109)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

I have checked through my code multiple times but I cannot find my error. I know it is something to do with my AsycTask my I really don't see where. All help is appreciated and will be rewarded with bounty if possible. I can provide my other code if it is necessary.

My post request:

```
public Document postRequest(String loginURL, String username, String password, String studentID, Response res) {

    Document doc = null;

    try {

        doc = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36")
                .referrer("https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?gohome=true")
                .cookies(res.cookies())
                .data("j_username", username)
                .data("j_password", password)
                .post();

        Log.e("POST REQUEST", "Connecting to login page, posting credentials...");


    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }

    return doc;

}
```

Comment: I think you should provide `postRequest` code for more information

Comment: @ChungPham My networking code was working perfectly before I added the sharedPreferences feature to keep user logged in, and now this error has arisen

Comment: Error messages have `at com.aurum.gradebook.GradeFetcher.postRequest(GradeFetcher.java:57)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `username` or `password` is null, please check these values

You can download source code of jsoup at [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org/download) then find that in HttpConnection.java the following code

```
public KeyVal value(String value) {
        Validate.notNull(value, "Data value must not be null");
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: turns out it was a mis-typed bracket causing the problem in my SessionManager class which lead to the error you pointed out. Thanks for the response.